# Running a python script that reads folders ends up with "Winerror 5: Access is denied." I already tried running as admin

Tags: python, windows

The program is written in Python, specifically the folder that I'm trying to read is chosen using PyQt5's `QFileDialog`. The process used to work flawlessly but something changed, and I have no idea how to check.

Now I keep getting `Error in opening file: [WinError 5] Access is denied:` whenever I try to open literally any folder using that program. I just read the folders, I make do any changes to it.

I used a conda env to develop the program. I tried to create a new conda env, no luck. I tried re-creating the environment using poetry, still same. I tried using an admin powershell using both conda and poetry, still the same error.

I tried moving to another computer, tried conda and poetry and admin, still nothing.

I also tried resetting the permissions of all the files (both the folders I'm trying to open and the code for the program itself) using `icacls "FOLDER" /reset /t /c /l`, same error.

It used to work just fine until last week when this started to happen, and I haven't even made any changes to the file loader code since then (I was working on another part of the program).

---

**Might be related**: part of my script involves copying a file from one location to another. I'm just using `shutil.copy(Path(str(Path(__file__).parent) + r'\default_config.ini'), config_file_path)` (the paths are correct, I checked), but the copied file comes out blank. I also tried `shutil.copyfile`, same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), add a filter for Python and check where the access problem occurs.

Maybe you put that filename into a variable and inspect it in a debugger instead of using it directly in the copy command. From [the description](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) it looks as if you concatenate Paths using `/`, not `+`.